# how to restrict a wcf service to one client application only

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

We have a WCF Service, using WSHttpBinding and security mode set to Transport, as we are using SSL. We have also been asked to make sure the service can only be called by the 1 web application that uses it, is there any way to block other applications from talking to it?

The application and service are all running within a company intranet, but there would be other applications on that intranet as well, so they want us to block them out.  we tried setting the transport's clientCredentialType ="Windows"  but that keeps bringing up a prompt to login whenever accessing the site, the users do not want that, as they are already logging in once the site comes up.

Comment: To restrict it to one application you need authorization, not authentication.

Comment: ok is there a way to do that in wcf, either in the config files or through iis?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751480.aspx - it is more complicated than I like to implement, but that is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 1):

start here to get an overview
http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/
Some light reading...

the quick answer lies in how can you uniquely identify the Web application ?
Does it have its own APP pool on an IIS server ? And therefore could have its own user.
IS this user on The same Active directory.  Then your can base the security on the Application user.

You could potentially use a firewall to make sure the traffic only comes that Web server.
You could uses an X.509 cert issued to that server and change the Binding to required X.509.

Without knowing more about the environment its hard to know what to recommend.
The guide is good.  Start at solutions at a glance(page 13) to get a feel about your options and jump around from there. Unless you are patient enough to read the guide ;-)

Comment: service and web application will both be on the same server, could you let me know how i might be able to lock it via app pool, i could keep them in the same pool or 2 different ones on the same box.
Users who will use the application with be only those within the company's network, so within LDAP, but they will also have access to other applications, number of users will vary.

Comment: in IIS you should App Pools above Websites in IIS Manager.

Comment: sorry but not sure what you mean. i can create app pools for them, if that's what you mean, but how to restrict.

Comment: In IIS you can create a pool.   In teh advanced screen for the pool, put a specific user Id on the Pool.   Now assign you website to use the pool.  Then configure the WCF service to allow only that identity.